# Can a high GIS Stack Exchange reputation help me get hired to a GIS firm?

Tags: industry

I have seen this question come up before, but the previous questions are all related to Stack Overflow, which is more of programming community. I am about to graduate with a bachelor's degree in GIS and I want to hear professionals input on whether or not a high reputation can impact job searching.

Should a Stack Exchange profile be incorporated into a resume? I feel like a high reputation shows enthusiasm and knowledge in the community and should be displayed for any recruiter to view, but I am just coming out of college and just getting introduced to this large community.

Comment: While I appreciate this question, and I'd even add an answer....I'm sure you're going to get closed as "opinion based" or "too broad", or any other number of reasons. You may have a chance to keep this open in the meta? Best of luck to you

Comment: I'm sure it can't hurt!

Comment: The knowledge you will get from conscientiously answering questions might help you, indirectly. I suspect the rep, itself, will not. Unless you are very lucky. The "traditional" GIS world is still very ArcWhatever Desktop focussed, and I suspect very few recruiters looking to hire such people are active on here. In the Foss4G world, maybe a bit more, but you will need linux, scripting, Python, Javascript, algorithms, DB, cloud, etc knowledge, which will get you hired anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is totally impossible to answer without polling thousands of recruiters.

Comment: This would be fine to ask in the GIS Chat Room but not here on Main or in Meta.

Comment: It could also be a negative in the hiring process -- "You spend how many hours each day editing the postings of strangers?!  When would you be doing work for us?"